# change div by clicking on same link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have `#div1` and `#div2`. `#div` is visible by default while `#div2` is hidden. When clicking a link, I want to hide `#div1` and display `#div2`, when clicking again on the link I want to hide `#div2` and show `#div1` again.

With the following jQuery I can hide first div and display `#div2`, but I don't know how to display `#div1` when clicking again on the same link. Also how can I switch the link title according to the visible div (ie. switch to div1 or div2)

**HTML:**

```
<a class="switch" href="#">Switch to Div 2</a>

<div id="div1">Div1</div>
<div id="div2">Div2</div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(".switch").click(function() {
  $('#div1').hide();
  $('#div2').show();
});
```

**CSS:**

```
#div2 { 
   display: none; 
}
```

**Demo:**
http://jsfiddle.net/De4x2/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try [`toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/):

http://jsfiddle.net/94bUG/

```
$(".switch").click(function() {
  $('#div1, #div2').toggle();
  // the following line switches the text
  $(this).text('Switch to Div ' + ($('#div1').is(':visible') ? '2' : '1'));
});
```